# Facebook authorization: oauth_token vs access_token, auth dialog

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, authorization, oauth-2.0

I want to create facebook app. In [this official tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/) I see, that:

- facebook user enter to my app `https://apps.facebook.com/app-name/`
- first I have to recieve POST query with **signed_request** argument to my server app
- Parsing **signed_request**.
- I see, there are no user_id or oauth_token in **signed_request**, and I can't see **code** argument, so I redirect to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/` or `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize` (what difference between these to links?)
- User add my app, gives me permission.
- Then I get POST query with **code** and **signed_request** arguments.
- I see in **signed_request** oauth_token.

Question: After that I must use this oauth_token, like access_token for Facebook Graph API, or
I must create query to `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` with **code**, and then I receive access_token, which I must use.

So, again:

1. oauth_token vs access_token
2. `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/` vs `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize`

Comment: If you are getting a `signed_request` parameter, then you’re obviously inside of a canvas or page tab iframe. How login works for those, is explained in these docs sub-chapters: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas/, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/